# VSTO:Prevent specific AppointmentItems to be converted to recurring AppointmentItems

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to build a Outlook AddIn. In certain cases I want to know whether the user is trying to convert the current AppointmentItem to a recurring AppointmentItem. 
Is it possible to catch this event? Is it possible to prevent the event from happening in certain cases?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the `AppointmentItem.PropertyChange("IsRecurring")` event - it will fire whenever the recurrence pattern is changed. You can then prompt the user and call `AppointmentItem.ClearRecurencePattern()`.

`AppointmentItem` can be retrieved from `Inspector.CurrentItem`, and inspector can be retrieved from the `Inspectors.NewInspector` event.

Comment: I managed to catch the event and to call ClearRecurrencePattern(). Although I think that calling ClearRecurrencePattern will result in the PropertyChanged Event to get fired again and again. So how do I avoid an endless loop?

Comment: You can check the value of the RecurrenceState property - no reason to do anything if it is 0 (OlRecurrenceState.olApptNotRecurring). Take a look at the appointments and their events in OutlookSpy (click Item and IMessage buttons).